# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute ``

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error when am trying to create a record in Model

```rb
Model.create(
  name: "test",
  brand_id: 1,
  equipment_type_id: 1,
  application_type: 1,
  model_number: "1234"
)
```

> ```
> ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute ``
> ```

why it is not giving the name of the attribute also?

Comment: Please, share your code.

Comment: can you show records table ?

Comment: Make sure you have all the attributes in the table. Or you can also check from schema.